# Epplus LoadFromData set with byteArray to ExcelPicture

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I have a working excel export for my dataSet however I would like to add images to the export, currently they are saved as byteArrays and show up in the export as `System.byteArray` how can I get this to display an image.

The data set is very large and it wont be feasible to add the images in after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed a solution by filling the workSheet, then searching the dataSet for any byte[] variables then insert the image into that cell, not ideal but it works